Not able to use multiple notebook at a time
I have recently shifted to Macbook Pro M3 and having problem in running multiple notebook at a time. In Ubuntu I could open as many notebook as I want directly by clicking the notebooks. Now in Mac, if I open a second notebook then it is automatically getting connected to the previous one and whatever I am doing in the 2nd one, it is affecting the 1st one. I have to manually launch mathematical from terminal each time and then select notebook from there. But I want to open multiple notebooks directly from finder by clicking on the notebook. Is there a way? Any help would be appreciated.

This is completely normal and expected, as all the notebooks you open are using the same kernel. You can either set a different kernel for each notebook, or use a different context for each notebook by clicking Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to This Notebook in the menu.

Thanks a lot. It resolved the issue.
